# GET operation to return image/file from REST api?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm developing a backend for pushing images together with some image data to a server. Using the ModelViewSet there is default support for the CRUD operations.

When issuing a GET operation (tested with Curl) I can get all the data concerning the uploaded images (e.g. 'name', 'path-to-file', 'category' etc.). Now I'm interested in getting the actual image as a returned object when performing a GET operation.

Is it suitable to use the REST api for such actions or should another approach be taken?

If it's suitable, should I override GET/.retrieve() and create a custom renderer as described in the Django Rest Framework API Guide?

(Realized that the last part should be tested before asked but that approach came to me now when writing)

Comment: REST is not about json but url structure. Just make a subresource i.e. /api/images/xx/data that will serve raw image. Or even better, add a url to raw image in the json response and serve the image directly

Comment: Yes, I would follow the REST API. It is generally the way to go and the actual image data can be considered as "just another information", like the name, category... Consequently, I would also follow the Guide.

Comment: Ok, will go for the REST API solution first and see what I can come up with. I'll post my solution when done. Thanks!

Comment: So, I did an implementation by creating a Renderer (as described in http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers) and wrapping up the file in a django.core.servers.basehttp.FileWrapper before returning it. Possibly not the best solution but It will do for now (hobby project).